# ¿Que jerarquia de ficheros utilizar en Firebase Cloud Storage? ¿hay alguna convención?

Tags: javascript, firebase, storage

**¿al tener varios  usuarios que estructura de ficheros debo usar?**

lo que estaba viendo como solución es crear una carpeta "users" y hay dentro pongo carpetas con "uid" de los usuarios y ahí cada uno de sus imágenes y videos:

`/users> /USER_UID > /ALL_USER_FILES`

¿Cómo lo debería de hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, la jerarquia que utilizas es la siguiente

```
users 
|____ uid
          |__ userData
```

De esta forma tienes una colección llamada **users** , dentro de esta colección tienes documentos con el id de cada usuario que lo obtienes con `currentUser.uid` y luego dentro de este documento la información de dicho usuario.

No existe una convencion particular, pero en la mayoria de los casos lo que quieres hacer es almacenar una colección que contiene usuarios, y cada usuario se identifica por su userID por lo cual esta bien pensar que una coleccion usuarios deberia contener a cada usuario por su ID , y cada userID tiene que tener su información

Comment: gracias lo tendre en cuenta.